# Using sources from Github to Android Eclipse

Tags: android

How exactly do I use sources from Github?
For example :

https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Or

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Or even 
https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions

[just giving examples]

After downloading the full sources off the net, what do I do with them? I've imported them into Eclipse and added the library into my Project. But I get lots of errors.

Any help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

git clone https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere.git

git clone https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders.git

git clone https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions.git

Typing these into the cmd prompt will download a copy of the source code to the current directory. Once cloned you can import the source into Eclipse.

Comment: I used the Windows GUI and clone them already. I've already imported them into my project too. Then what do I do next? For example the ViewPageExtensions.